# Migrating CRM data from one dataverse environment to another

Tags: migration, dynamics-crm, powerapps, dataverse

I am fairly new to this so I would need a step by step guidance to be able to do my task.
I am looking for a simple way to migrate some CRM tables from one Sandbox environment to a Production environment.
I believe we do not have the licenses to create an Azure Data Lake, and we would like to build a robust solution.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: it best to try out something and ask questions about issues encountered rather than asking such open-ended questions

Answer (score 1):

There is a XRMToolBox control called "Data Migration using FetchXml". You can specify columns and filter criteria in the fetchXml and data according to that query will be transferred from source to target.

Here are the steps.

1. In the source instance go to advanced find (Microsoft removed it from UCI, but still available in "Advanced Settings"), specify columns, and filter criteria of the entity which data should be migrated.
2. Download the fetchXml file from the advanced find.
3. Add fetchXml file in the XrmToolBox control.
4. Click "Transfer Data".

https://marketplace.bevercrm.com/.../DataMigrationUsingFetchXml

https://www.xrmtoolbox.com/.../DataMigrationUsingFetchXml

https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/microsoft-dynamics-crm-forum/251174/migrating-data-from-dynamics-365-sandbox-to-dynamics-365-production/1299075

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on the scenario and the type of data however there are two easy options to look at.

If you are only looking to do a once off migration of simple data you can look at something like the configuration migration tool from Microsoft.
Here is some [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/manage-configuration-data) on how it works.

If it is something you need to run more often then look at [KingwaySoft](https://www.kingswaysoft.com/products/ssis-integration-toolkit-for-microsoft-dynamics-crm)'s SSIS offering.